# HTTP2 push and native ES modules: "entry" module push is ignored

Tags: http2, es6-modules

I’ve been experimenting with approaches to serving native ES modules over HTTP2. Pretty much everything works great (where supported), but there’s a quirk that I can’t make much sense of.

Given a request for the / document, I push the resources which directly or indirectly are known to be dependencies of that document. In this case that ends up being three additional resources that piggyback via pushes:

- /index.css (a dependency via `<link href ...>`)
- /index.js (a dependency via `<script type="module" src ...>`
- /routes.js (an indirect dependency, imported by `index.js`)

All three resources appear to push successfully from the server side. However, Chrome makes a second request for "/index.js" despite the push with the first request. Neither of the other two resources are requested; those pushed responses appear to be acknowledged correctly.

At first I thought this was a Chrome quirk, just a rough edge on a newly minted feature. But the same behavior is demonstrated in Firefox when the module support flag is enabled, which made me wonder if this is deliberate for some reason.

[image: network activity]

Logging from backend corresponding to above requests:

```
RECEIVED REQUEST: GET /
...PUSHING /index.css
...PUSHING /index.js
...PUSHING /routes.js
RECEIVED REQUEST: GET /index.js
...PUSHING /routes.js
```

---

Following up on the instructions from @sbordet: here are transcripts from both requests (great to know this stuff can be introspected in Chrome!):

### First Req (/)

```
3067: HTTP2_SESSION
death.tips:443 (DIRECT)
Start Time: 2017-10-09 10:49:24.597

t=304289 [st= 0] +HTTP2_SESSION  [dt=?]
                  --> host = "death.tips:443"
                  --> proxy = "DIRECT"
t=304289 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_INITIALIZED
                    --> protocol = "h2"
                    --> source_dependency = 3064 (SOCKET)
t=304289 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS
                    --> settings = ["[id:1 (SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE) value:65536]","[id:3 (SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS) value:1000]","[id:4 (SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE) value:6291456]"]
t=304289 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 15663105
                    --> window_size = 15728640
t=304289 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_WINDOW_UPDATE
                    --> delta = 15663105
                    --> stream_id = 0
t=304289 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_HEADERS
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> fin = true
                    --> has_priority = true
                    --> :method: GET
                        :authority: death.tips
                        :scheme: https
                        :path: /
                        pragma: no-cache
                        cache-control: no-cache
                        upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3236.0 Safari/537.36
                        accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
                        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                        accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
                    --> parent_stream_id = 0
                    --> source_dependency = 3060 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
                    --> stream_id = 1
                    --> weight = 256
t=304310 [st=21]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS
t=304310 [st=21]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS_ACK
t=304313 [st=24]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS_ACK
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_PUSH_PROMISE
                    --> :scheme: https
                        :authority: death.tips
                        :path: /index.css
                        :method: GET
                    --> id = 1
                    --> promised_stream_id = 2
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_STREAM_SEND_PRIORITY
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> parent_stream_id = 1
                    --> stream_id = 2
                    --> weight = 110
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_PUSH_PROMISE
                    --> :scheme: https
                        :authority: death.tips
                        :path: /index.js
                        :method: GET
                    --> id = 1
                    --> promised_stream_id = 4
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_STREAM_SEND_PRIORITY
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> parent_stream_id = 2
                    --> stream_id = 4
                    --> weight = 110
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_PUSH_PROMISE
                    --> :scheme: https
                        :authority: death.tips
                        :path: /routes.js
                        :method: GET
                    --> id = 1
                    --> promised_stream_id = 6
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_STREAM_SEND_PRIORITY
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> parent_stream_id = 4
                    --> stream_id = 6
                    --> weight = 110
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        cache-control: public, max-age=0
                        content-encoding: deflate
                        content-length: 388
                        content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                        date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:49:24 GMT
                        etag: "c3QDLn1lTsAqsErFvMgM3bEsUsY="
                        last-modified: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:43:24 GMT
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        cache-control: public, max-age=0
                        content-encoding: deflate
                        content-length: 88
                        content-type: text/css
                        date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:49:24 GMT
                        etag: "/qkigeCvJgEE+0+5YhHLgByhKL0="
                        last-modified: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:43:24 GMT
                    --> stream_id = 2
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        cache-control: public, max-age=0
                        content-encoding: deflate
                        content-length: 60
                        content-type: text/javascript
                        date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:49:24 GMT
                        etag: "/+cUWoFWkafsB6vSI5wBuB7v4Tk="
                        last-modified: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:43:24 GMT
                    --> stream_id = 4
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        cache-control: public, max-age=0
                        content-encoding: deflate
                        content-length: 64
                        content-type: text/javascript
                        date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:49:24 GMT
                        etag: "2ZM3pEXqn9z1d5tkBr2x5kdHsGk="
                        last-modified: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:43:24 GMT
                    --> stream_id = 6
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 388
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -388
                    --> window_size = 15728252
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 88
                    --> stream_id = 2
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -88
                    --> window_size = 15728164
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 2
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 60
                    --> stream_id = 4
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -60
                    --> window_size = 15728104
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 4
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 64
                    --> stream_id = 6
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -64
                    --> window_size = 15728040
t=304336 [st=47]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 6
t=304337 [st=48]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 388
                    --> window_size = 15728428
t=304342 [st=53]    HTTP2_STREAM_ADOPTED_PUSH_STREAM
                    --> stream_id = 2
                    --> url = "https://death.tips/index.css"
t=304343 [st=54]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 88
                    --> window_size = 15728516
```

### Second Req (/index.js)

```
3085: HTTP2_SESSION
death.tips:443 (DIRECT)
Start Time: 2017-10-09 10:49:24.694

t=304386 [st= 0] +HTTP2_SESSION  [dt=?]
                  --> host = "death.tips:443"
                  --> proxy = "DIRECT"
t=304386 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_INITIALIZED
                    --> protocol = "h2"
                    --> source_dependency = 3084 (SOCKET)
t=304386 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS
                    --> settings = ["[id:1 (SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE) value:65536]","[id:3 (SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS) value:1000]","[id:4 (SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE) value:6291456]"]
t=304386 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 15663105
                    --> window_size = 15728640
t=304386 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_WINDOW_UPDATE
                    --> delta = 15663105
                    --> stream_id = 0
t=304386 [st= 0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_HEADERS
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> fin = true
                    --> has_priority = true
                    --> :method: GET
                        :authority: death.tips
                        :scheme: https
                        :path: /index.js
                        pragma: no-cache
                        cache-control: no-cache
                        origin: https://death.tips
                        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3236.0 Safari/537.36
                        accept: */*
                        referer: https://death.tips/
                        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                        accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
                    --> parent_stream_id = 0
                    --> source_dependency = 3080 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
                    --> stream_id = 1
                    --> weight = 220
t=304405 [st=19]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS
t=304405 [st=19]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS_ACK
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS_ACK
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_PUSH_PROMISE
                    --> :scheme: https
                        :authority: death.tips
                        :path: /routes.js
                        :method: GET
                    --> id = 1
                    --> promised_stream_id = 2
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_STREAM_SEND_PRIORITY
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> parent_stream_id = 1
                    --> stream_id = 2
                    --> weight = 110
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        cache-control: public, max-age=0
                        content-encoding: deflate
                        content-length: 60
                        content-type: text/javascript
                        date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:49:24 GMT
                        etag: "/+cUWoFWkafsB6vSI5wBuB7v4Tk="
                        last-modified: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:43:24 GMT
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        cache-control: public, max-age=0
                        content-encoding: deflate
                        content-length: 64
                        content-type: text/javascript
                        date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:49:24 GMT
                        etag: "2ZM3pEXqn9z1d5tkBr2x5kdHsGk="
                        last-modified: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:43:24 GMT
                    --> stream_id = 2
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 60
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -60
                    --> window_size = 15728580
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 64
                    --> stream_id = 2
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -64
                    --> window_size = 15728516
t=304409 [st=23]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 2
t=304410 [st=24]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 60
                    --> window_size = 15728576
t=304412 [st=26]    HTTP2_STREAM_ADOPTED_PUSH_STREAM
                    --> stream_id = 2
                    --> url = "https://death.tips/routes.js"
t=304413 [st=27]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 64
                    --> window_size = 15728640
```

Comment: In case it’s relevant: backend is node, and I observed this behavior using both the userland http2/SPDY package and the new node-core http2 module.

Comment: The screenshot does not show `index.js` as being first pushed and then request again by the browser. There could be some issue pushing `index.js` so that Chrome discards it. Can you please retry with Chrome and: go to chrome://net-internals, then choose "HTTP/2" in the left panel, and the connection to your server in the middle panel. On the right panel you should see a detailed dump of the HTTP/2 traffic, including pushes. Report it here for further analysis.

Comment: Thanks sbordet, I didn’t realize there were built-in tools for this. Chrome transcript of the exchanges added to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was quite a mystery!

The issue is that — well, I’m not gonna be able to explain this well, but my shallow understanding is that documents are requested "with credentials", but `<script type="module">` triggers, by default, a "no credentials" request. The push promise for the script is "with credentials" by association, but `never the twain shall meet`. So the browser must make a new request because the push promise "doesn’t count". And there *is* a solution:

```
<script type="module" src="/index.js" crossorigin="use-credentials">
```

I would never have thought to use a "`crossorigin`" attribute to fetch a resource on the same site, but there it is. Push gets adopted, and my little experiment just got twice as *fast.*

---

Here’s the transcript of [the whole conversation in #whatwg](http://logs.glob.uno/?c=freenode%23whatwg&s=9%20Oct%202017&e=10%20Oct%202017#c1039776):

```
[7:35pm] <bathos> I’ve got a question about interactions between module
  loading and HTTP2 that’s had me scratching my head for a few days — is
  that something appropriate to ask about here?
[7:37pm] <jyasskin> bathos: Yes.
[7:39pm] <bathos> Cool. I’ve been experimenting with serving resources using
  HTTP2 push — assemble a dep graph in advance and follow through on
  requests by provisioning their known dependencies as push promises. This
  works great on the whole, but there’s a quirk I’ve observed that seems to
  be related specifically to ES module "entrypoints".
[7:40pm] <bathos> I asked about it on SO, so there’s a bit of detail in the
  question and comments there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642569/http2-push-and-native-es-modules-entry-module-push-is-ignored
[7:40pm] <bathos> The gist though:
[7:41pm] <bathos> Given a request for a document which contains
  <script type="module" src="something">, and an http2 session which
  includes a push promise for "something", the "something" push is never
  adopted. Instead, the browser makes a fresh request for it.
[7:41pm] <jyasskin> Domenic: ^
[7:42pm] <bathos> Dependencies imported _in_ ES are adopted.
[7:42pm] <jyasskin> bathos: I'm not an expert here, but your question
  reminds me of the with-vs-no-credentials problem in
  https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/354.
[7:42pm] <bathos> And if I reference the same module in a different way in
  the root document, e.g. a preload <link>, it is successfully adopted. It’s
  peculiar to type="module"
[7:43pm] <bathos> oh, interesting
[7:43pm] <jyasskin> Apologies if I've just sent you on a wild goose chase.
[7:44pm] <bathos> I have been on a lot for the last two days haha! Since
  HTTP2 is still pretty mysterious to me, it’d been hard to rule out the
  possibility that I’m doing something weird there, though I’m pretty sure
  at this point that I’m not.
[7:52pm] <bathos> jyasskin you genius!
[7:53pm] <jyasskin> s/genius/pattern-matcher/ :)
[7:53pm] <bathos> crossorigin="use-credentials" in the doc actually makes
  the module push promise get adopted
[7:54pm] <bathos> I never would have thought to try "crossorigin" on a file
  on the same host haha
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser activity is the following:

- send request (stream=1)
- receive push promise for `/index.css` (stream=2)
- receive push promise for `/index.js` (stream=4)
- receive push promise for `/routes.js` (stream=6)
- receive headers for stream=1
- receive headers for stream=2
- receive headers for stream=4
- receive headers for stream=6
- receive data for stream=1 (388+0 bytes)
- receive data for stream=2 (88+0 bytes)
- receive data for stream=4 (60+0 bytes)
- receive data for stream=6 (64+0 bytes)

My interpretation is that the browser receives the whole body for the primary request (stream=1) *before* it receives the whole body for the pushed resources.

I'm guess internally the browser starts parsing the HTML, figure out it needs `/index.js`, find that it is not yet arrived although it has been promised, and therefore it issues a request for it.

The browser probably needs `/index.css` later than it needs `/index.js`, and by the time it needs the CSS it has already arrived to the browser as a pushed resource, and that would explain why `/index.css` is used from the push cache.

If you can control when the resources are written to the network, try to send the whole body of `/index.js` before sending the HTML body. That should make the browser aware that `index.js` is fully available in the push cache and use it from there, rather than requesting it anew.

A final note that the push cache implementation in Chrome has varied greatly over the years/months, so what could be true today may not hold in the future.

Comment: That makes sense, but I can see that the push stream requests all finish before the end of the transaction. However this provides a lot of help! The css is earlier in the doc, not later — but CSS is _blocking_, while ES modules are inherently deferred, that is, the browser tries to load the CSS immediately but will not try to load an ES module until document.close() has occurred. And document.close() does not occur until the "base" request’s body has completed, yet I have conflated closing the whole request with ending that payload (owing to using HTTP1 compat API). [...]

Comment: [...] If my hunch is correct, a push stream can’t be utilized ("adopted") after the session is closed regardless of other factors, and I must look for an approach that keeps the http2 session open after the original "request" has been fulfilled. Will report back tonight on whether that works.

Comment: I would be careful in assuming _blocking_ behaviors in the browser implementation. Last time I looked, browser implementations outsmarted by far any naive reasoning such as "the CSS is earlier in the doc", or references to `document.close()`. What the browser does at the network level, and what then does at the rendering level are two very different things, and may not be related much.

Comment: A push stream can certainly be used _before_ the HTTP/2 session is closed (the `index.css` case). You cannot control when the HTTP/2 session is closed, so your second comment is not correct. You want to try to send `index.js` before the HTML content.

Comment: That’s a good point, re: network level, but I mentioned document.close() — not
the literal method, but rather the doc’s open/closed status — because of its
unusual interactions with script resources; it seemed like a good avenue to
explore. However it was not fruitful [...]

Comment: I tried a fairly different approach to serving the response. This is with the
new node http2 native module, and previously I’d been using its
HTTP1-backwards-compatibility API. Avoiding that simplified things. However the
results did not change. [...]

Comment: So I tried another test. I added `<link rel="preload" href="/index.js" as="script">`
to the document. That works! The original session’s index.js push is adopted
when I provide a preload link — _and then the browser requests it again anyway!_ It is beginning to look like this is an issue more about how browsers handle ES modules rather than the HTTP2 part.

Comment: So, just to clarify: I believe I’ve established that the issue is not order-related. The pushed `/index.js` resource is successfully adopted in the first transaction when it is referenced in the document with `<link>`, just not when it is referenced with `<script>`; and even then, a fresh request is made if `<script>` is present. Also notable: it does not make this request using `if-none-match` with the etag from the previously received push response, even though the network waterfall shows that it finished receiving that one prior to making the second request. Pretty mysterious...